# How can I call a Bootstrap 3 modal on an element that doesn't exist yet?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to call a Bootstrap modal on an element that only gets created when a button is clicked first. I don't have access to the HTML to add it.

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( "#newsletter-validate-detail button" ).click(function(e) {
   //  e.preventDefault();
    console.log('button was clicked');
    jQuery('#advice-validate-email-newsletterl').live(function() {
        consol.log('message is live');
        jQuery('#advice-validate-email-newsletterl').modal('show');
    }).

});
```

There are no console errors.

Comment: Are you saying that `#newsletter-validate-detail button` is dynamically created? and then you want to bind an modal event to it?

Comment: Show the code that creates the modal

Answer (score 1):

Since the button is not in the DOM at load, you have to use the `.on` method.

```
$(document).on("click", "#newsletter-validate-detail", function(){
   $('#myModal').modal({show:true})

})
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/449o9d6x/2/